# How do I solve the error when running build xml file in ant build?

Tags: liferay, liferay-developer-studio

I'm new to programming and coding. I was working on liferay portal and tried to make a portlet. when I tried to run the build.xml on ant build it threw error which I didn't understand.

this is my consloe

Buildfile: C:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-1.0.13-20171018150113838\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.13\portlets\welcome-portlet\build.xml

deploy:
[java] Java Result: 1
[echo] Using native Sass compiler
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll :
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.liferay.sass.compiler.jni.internal.libsass.LiferaysassLibrary.sassMakeFileContext(J)J
[echo]    at com.liferay.sass.compiler.jni.internal.libsass.LiferaysassLibrary.sassMakeFileContext(Native Method)
[echo]    at com.liferay.sass.compiler.jni.internal.libsass.LiferaysassLibrary.sassMakeFileContext(LiferaysassLibrary.java:1275)
[echo]    at com.liferay.sass.compiler.jni.internal.JniSassCompiler.createSassFileContext(JniSassCompiler.java:235)
[echo]    at com.liferay.sass.compiler.jni.internal.JniSassCompiler.compileFile(JniSassCompiler.java:91)
[echo]    at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder._parseSass(CSSBuilder.java:350)
[echo]    at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder._parseSassFile(CSSBuilder.java:364)
[echo]    at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder.execute(CSSBuilder.java:161)
[echo]    at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder.main(CSSBuilder.java:109)
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[echo] # BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\BridJExtractedLibraries15268401749919806123\liferaysass.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-1.0.13-20171018150113838\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.13\build-common.xml:2731: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-1.0.13-20171018150113838\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.13\build-common.xml:1401: The following error occurred while executing this line:
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-1.0.13-20171018150113838\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.13\build-common.xml:2318: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-1.0.13-20171018150113838\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-1.0.13\build-common.xml:183: Sass to CSS Builder generated exceptions.

Total time: 3 minutes 15 seconds

can anyone help me with this